# Bad grade in thesis, a paper submitted, can this help?

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions

I am a master student, wish to apply pure math PhD. I receive a bad grade in my thesis. My undergrad major is not the field I want to apply. The only thing I got is I have a submitted paper in mathematics(being the only author). Can this help my application? If the paper are published, do I still got chance to get any PhD offer?

Comment: Applying to a pure math Ph.D. program with a different undergrad major is fine.  But it will be better if your undergrad studies include the important undergrad math courses.  (Abstract algebra, real analysis, linear algebra ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will help as it is a positive indicator of research interest and success.

But it is impossible to say whether you have a chance or not. Only by going through the application process can you learn that.

Some places can be pretty sophisticated about interpreting "bad" grades for the thesis. If top marks are rare at your institution, that may be known.

If you apply, make a broad search for a position. Don't choose only high or only low ranked institutions. In the US your application will be judged by a committee. Other places by a professor that you need to communicate with. In the US, the undergraduate degree can be in a different field.

There are lots of variables, but if you don't apply, you don't get accepted.